# Assembly.LoadFile look dependencies in Location of Executeable

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I wrote a wrapper class which loads other assemblies using reflection. Wrapper.dll is also being loaded by a process through reflection following is the diagram to explain the scenario.

```
Process.exe  
         |___Loads__ Wrapper.dll  
                         |_______Loads___1.dll  
                                           |___ Depends___ xyz.dll
```

Following is the file Structure

```
Root
  |___A  
  |   |__Process.exe  
  |___B  
      |__Wrapper.dll   
      |__C
         |__1.dll
         |__xyz.dll
```

I am using `Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\root\B\C\1.dll");` function to load the `1.dll` in `Wrapper.dll` however it fails to find the dependencies as it tries to find the dependencies in `A` dir, the same directory where we have process executable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution I just changed the `Assembly.LoadFile` to `Assembly.LoadFrom` and its loaded perfectly fine. You can read the explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  However following is the crust of it.

> **Load-From Context**
>
> The load-from context lets you load an assembly from a path that is
>   not under the application path, and therefore is not included in
>   probing. It enables dependencies to be located and loaded from that
>   path, because the path information is maintained by the context. In
>   addition, assemblies in this context can use dependencies that are
>   loaded into the default load context.

Comment: I get this: Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' : 'The assembly named 'xxx' was loaded from 'file:///C:/xxx.dll' using the LoadFrom context. The use of this context can result in unexpected behavior for serialization, casting and dependency resolution. In almost all cases, it is recommended that the LoadFrom context be avoided. This can be done by installing assemblies in the Global Assembly Cache or in the ApplicationBase directory and using Assembly.Load when explicitly loading assemblies.'